# e2e how to test login sucess case in angular protractor

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

Just started with e2e and I want to test the login success case in Angular app. So here is my test case

```
it("when login is successful — user object should be set in storage", () => {
        loginPage.fillCredentials();

        // wait until redirected to new lage
        const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        const elm = element(by.css(".logo-text"));
        browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elm), 40000);
        expect(loginPage.getLocalStorageObject("currentUser")).toBeDefined();
        const currentUser = JSON.parse(loginPage.getLocalStorageObject("currentUser"));
        expect(currentUser.CarrierId).toBeDefined();
    });
```

And

```
fillCredentials(credentials: any = this.credentials): any {
   this.getFormField("email").sendKeys(credentials.userName);
   this.getFormField("password").sendKeys(credentials.password);
   element(by.css("button[aria-label='Login']")).click();
}

getLocalStorageObject(key): any {
    browser.executeScript(`return window.localStorage.getItem('${key}');`);
}
```

I am providing the correct user credentials and then hit login button.

In the app when login is done with correct credentials it sets the `currectUser` object in `localStorage` and redirect to page that is returned from the login page.

But my test case is getting failed

```
when login is successful — user object should be set in storage
      - Expected undefined to be defined.
```

I am using wait function like this in `it`

```
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
const elm = element(by.css(".logo-text"));
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elm), 40000);
```

where `.logo-text` class is the element present on the redirected page.

Is this the right approach or something else needs to done?

Comment: Did you try with `browser.wait(EC.presenceOf($('.logo-text')), 40000);` instead?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend doing the following:

Turn off the control flow of Protractor and switch to the async/await syntax. The control flow feature is deprecated see [docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md).

In my experience understanding what happens behind the scene with the control flow is much harder than switching to async/await syntax. This will give you complete control over how the code gets executed.
You can do this by adding `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` to your protractor config file.

So you code snippets would have to be written like so:

```
it("when login is successful — user object should be set in storage", async() => {
        await loginPage.fillCredentials();

        // wait until redirected to new lage
        const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        const elm = element(by.css(".logo-text"));
        await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elm), 40000);
        expect(await loginPage.getLocalStorageObject("currentUser")).toBeDefined();
        const currentUser = JSON.parse(loginPage.getLocalStorageObject("currentUser"));
        expect(currentUser.CarrierId).toBeDefined();
    });
```

```
async fillCredentials(credentials: any = this.credentials): Promise<void> {
   await this.getFormField("email").sendKeys(credentials.userName);
   await this.getFormField("password").sendKeys(credentials.password);
   await element(by.css("button[aria-label='Login']")).click();
}


getLocalStorageObject(key): Promise<void> {
    return browser.executeScript(`return window.localStorage.getItem(arguments[0]);`, key);
}
```

In your `getLocalStorageObject` function you forgot to return the value. And you can't pass variables like this into the executeScript function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: still saying `TimeoutError: Wait timed out after 62063ms`

Comment: @SunilGarg is there a way you can share me github repo with this example?

Comment: yeah I wll share and comment the link. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution from [nephi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4296595/nephi) should work. If it doesn't add the following lines of code to his solution

```
const elm = element(by.css(".logo-text"));
await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elm), 40000);
await loginPage.getLocalStorageObject("currentUser"))
        .then((user)=>{
           expect(user).toBeDefined();
        });
```

Comment: you mean, i should not write the above lines?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Token Check or URL redirect check :

```
  it('should login with success , Token Check', async () => {
   
  
    const emailInput: ElementFinder = page.getEmailInput();
    const passwordInput: ElementFinder = page.getPasswordInput();        
    const loginBtn: ElementFinder = page.getLoginBtn();


    const userToken = 'test_token';
    emailInput.sendKeys('login@gmail.com');
    passwordInput.sendKeys('password');

    loginBtn.click();

    const localStorageToken = await browser.executeScript('return localStorage.getItem("_token");');
    expect(localStorageToken).toEqual(userToken);

});
```

using URL redirect Check :

```
      it('should login with success ,  Url Redirect Check', async () => {
   
  
    const emailInput: ElementFinder = page.getEmailInput();
    const passwordInput: ElementFinder = page.getPasswordInput();        
    const loginBtn: ElementFinder = page.getLoginBtn();


    const userToken = 'test_token';
    emailInput.sendKeys('login@gmail.com');
    passwordInput.sendKeys('password');

    loginBtn.click();

    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(browser.baseUrl + '/home');

});
```

you need to implement also getEmailInput() , getPasswordInput() , getLoginBtn() in your page.po.ts

for exemple :

```
getEmailInput(): ElementFinder {
    return element(by.css('.email-input'));
}

getPasswordInput(): ElementFinder {
    return element(by.css('.password-input'));
}

getLoginBtn(): ElementFinder {
    return element(by.css('.login-btn'));
}
```